# Can't get passed render blocking css/js issue with Page Speed Insights

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, google-pagespeed, mod-deflate

I am trying to optimize my website to be as fast as possible. On [Google Page Speed Insights](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/), I have been going through the recommendations, and have gotten a lot done. One thing I can't seem to get passed is the render blocking css/js issue. I have an .htaccess file where I am compressing my css, and javascript with mod_deflate. I read that mod_deflate is the best way to get passed this issue, but I am still getting the render blocking problem with one css file, `https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css`

I initially though it might be because, since it is a CDN, it was not being compressed with the rest of my files, but I have been reading that a solution to get past the render block css/js is to use CDNs. Is there anyway to fix this without writing a lot of critical inline styles ? Maybe something extra I need to put in my .htaccess file, or a way I can load the CDN ?

.htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"

</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_gzip.c>
mod_gzip_on Yes
mod_gzip_dechunk Yes
mod_gzip_item_include file .(html?|txt|css|js|php|pl)$
mod_gzip_item_include handler ^cgi-script$
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^text/.*
mod_gzip_item_include mime ^application/x-javascript.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude mime ^image/.*
mod_gzip_item_exclude rspheader ^Content-Encoding:.*gzip.*
</ifModule>

#Begin gzip and deflate
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>

# compress text, html, javascript, css, xml:
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/png
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/jpg
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html

# DEFLATE NOT COMPATIBLE BROWERS
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header append Vary User-Agent
</IfModule>

</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_pagespeed_ap24.c>
ModPagespeed on
ModPagespeedInheritVHostConfig on
ModPagespeedEnableFilters rewrite_css,combine_css
ModPagespeedEnableFilters recompress_images
ModPagespeedEnableFilters convert_png_to_jpeg,convert_jpeg_to_webp
ModPagespeedEnableFilters collapse_whitespace,remove_comments
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download "bootstrap.min.css" from CDN and host it on your own server and then call it on the footer of your website and your problem will be solved.

Regards
Manoj Soni